# How do I supply an argument to a parameterized method, whose type I don't know until runtime?

Tags: java, generics, casting

In this code snippet:

```
...
Executor<? extends Data> executor = someOtherThing.getExecutor();
Data data = someOtherOtherThing.getData();

executor.execute(data);
...

interface Executor<T extends Data> {
    void execute(T data);
}
```

So both the `executor` and the `data` are coming in from somewhere else, and I don't know their actual types until run time, but I do know that the type of `data` is the same as `executor`'s parameterised type, `T`.

I assume that some sort of cast is needed to allow `executor.execute(data)`, but I don't know what to cast to, or how to do it, without knowing the exact type until runtime. How can I make this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you have there? Where do you expect to need to cast?

Comment: The code doesn't compile: `The method execute(capture#4-of ? extends Data) in the type Executor<capture#4-of ? extends Data> is not applicable for the arguments (Data)`

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but the usual approach in similar situations is to use a class variable.

Comment: That `someOtherThing`, is it type-parametrized?

Comment: @chrylis: In a nutshell, the code snippet above is a compile error, because the compiler doesn't know that `data` is of the same type as `T`. So how do I avoid the compile error?

Comment: @RealSkeptic no, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

> but I do know that the type of data is the same as executor's
>   parameterised type, T

If you are sure, you can write:

```
Executor<? extends Data> executor = someOtherThing.getExecutor();
Data data = someOtherOtherThing.getData();

Executor<Data> executorData = (Executor<Data>)executor;

executorData.execute(data);
```

It works for

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> listNumbers = (List<Number>) list; //Unchecked cast: 'java.util.List<capture<? extends java.lang.Number>>' to 'java.util.List<java.lang.Number>
listNumbers.add(new Integer(1));
```